# FwpmEngineOpen fails at dispatch level

Tags: dispatch, irq, wfp

I am trying to add a WFP filter while holding an NDIS RW lock, but FwpmEngineOpen or FwpmTransactionBegin functions fail.
Is there a limitation that prevents these functions to work at Dispatch level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [FwpmEngineOpen0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that the requirement is IRQL == PASSIVE_LEVEL, so it won't work in DISPATCH_LEVEL.

Comment: You are right. The MSDN documentation mentions this for FwpmEngineOpen0, but not for FwpmTransactionBegin0 or other WFP management functions.  
Although I have found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that all of WFP management functions except FwpmFreeMemory0 must be running at IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL. Callers of FwpmFreeMemory0 must be running at IRQL <= DISPATCH_LEVEL.